# How to put a new line using StringIO in python?

Tags: python, stringio

```
import StringIO
output = StringIO.StringIO()   
output.write('this is the first line\n the new line should come here')
a = output.getvalue()
output.close()
print a
```

But the new line character `\n` does not get printed as a new line.

How do I get a newline?

Comment: Works on my computer.

Comment: What OS do you have? What you show shall work well. On my Ubuntu it prints new line. You might use MS Windows, if it really does not work there, I would try `\n\r`.

Comment: Check this post, is about make line break in mac osx:  [How do i create line break in terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190030/how-do-i-create-a-line-break-in-terminal)

Comment: Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 06:20:15) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import StringIO
>>> output=StringIO.StringIO()
>>> output.write('This is a new\nline and I \n amd')
>>> a=output.getvalue()
>>> a
'This is a new\nline and I \n amd'
>>>

Comment: @user3676102; rather than typing `a`; use `print(a)` as per your question. Do the newlines display correctly if you print? Your comment above is the way I'd expect Python to work.

Comment: works too on my Windows 8.1 x64 machine, Python 2.7.6

Comment: use `os.linesep` as the line separator character(s)